# Laravel 5 Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am new to Laravel(ver 5.5). This is **config/database.php** file:

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mfa'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypass'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

And here is my route on **routes/web.php**:

```
Route::get('/', function ()
{
    Schema::create('books',function($newtable){
        $newtable->increments('id');
        $newtable->string('writer');
        $newtable->string('title',500);
        $newtable->text('description');
        $newtable->date('published');
        $newtable->integer('copies');
        $newtable->timestamps();
    });
    return view('welcome');
});
```

The database exists and called 'mfa', the username is 'root'. It seems it is trying to log in as 'homestead' despite it is 'root'. This is an error code: **SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]**

Comment: well check your `.env` file present in the root directory of your laravel project

Comment: Check `.env` file or environment variables.

Comment: After there were the error, I have also edited it. The error stays the same after changing it. /.env:

Comment: @smus Can You Share Your `.env`file code

Comment: check out mysql users and the assignments of each user to databases

Answer (score 1):

Run This Command First to clear Cached:  `php artisan config:clear`

---

**.env File:**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Pf8bqFhStKix4rtdt1FOgvPpudMqsYyw+Uv+dOvaF8w=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mfa
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypass

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

---

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),  //127.0.0.1
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mfa'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'smus82'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

---

> **NOTE: You need to Restart The Server After Changing in `.env` file. to apply the settings.**

Comment: I know, I cleared the cache several times and reloaded the server

Comment: @smus  .. Which server you using ??

Comment: i don't know which server its you using right now, So Just try laravel server:-  `php artisan serve` and check its work ? or not !!

Comment: I knew about clearing the cache before. It did not solve the problem. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Restarting `php artisan serve` did the trick for me after editing `.env`

Answer (score 0):

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Pf8bqFhStKix4rtdt1FOgvPpudMqsYyw+Uv+dOvaF8w=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mfa
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypass

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```